# Sqlite3 repeats value in other dates

Tags: sqlite

.The involved tables:

data_incidencia.
[image: data_incidencia.]

data_ticket.

[image: data_ticket.]

My query is the following

```
select t1.hurtos, t2.fallas,t3.ticket, t1.fecha_carga
from 
(select count(ttc) as hurtos,
fecha_carga from data_incidencia
where campo_key_id = 2
group by fecha_carga) t1,
(select count(ttc) as fallas, 
fecha_carga from data_incidencia
where campo_key_id = 1
group by fecha_carga) t2,
(select count(ticket) as ticket, 
fecha_solicitud as fecha_carga from data_ticket ) t3 
where t1.fecha_carga =t2.fecha_carga;
```

and the output:

[image: output]

but the desired output is:

[image]

notice that "ticket" is repeating value in 2018-05-16 where is no tickets, is probably something dumb as case when or group by, but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas of how should i fix this query ?

Comment: Please edit your question, provide sample data for all tables involved, and then show us the expected output using that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You have three subqueries, `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`.

`t1` and `t2` are joined, but `t3` is not, so you get an implicit [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join).

The column names you're using look as if you want to join all three on the same column:

```
SELECT t1.hurtos, t2.fallas, t3.ticket, t1.fecha_carga
FROM (...) AS t1,
     (...) AS t2,
     (...) AS t3
WHERE t1.fecha_carga = t2.fecha_carga
  AND t1.fecha_carga = t3.fecha_carga;
```

And implicit joins are outdated since 1992; better use explicit joins:

```
SELECT t1.hurtos, t2.fallas, t3.ticket, fecha_carga
FROM (...) AS t1
JOIN (...) AS t2 USING (fecha_carga)
JOIN (...) AS t3 USING (fecha_carga);
```

Comment: I tryed both, but it just gives me 1 date.